# How to count the number of numerical values in a string

Tags: sql, presto

There is a column in a string format. Data in that column is a mixture of letters and numbers. I want to pick up rows which contain more than 4 numbers in it.

For example, in the table below, what I'm interested in is row_num 4 as it contains more than 4 numerical values. How can they be selected?

| row_num | column_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fje8q934yeufoeha |
| 2 | 08kfdjaehewaoffe |
| 3 | 6fdiuewwiaei3eew |
| 4 | jfe0293ujfid22fe |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT row_num, column_1
FROM yourTable
WHERE LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(column_1, '\D+', '')) > 4;
```